# Как сделать редирект с post данными?

Tags: php, http

Возможно ли сделать редирект с post данными? или единсвенный вариант использовать форму и js?

Comment: Редирект чего именно и куда?

Comment: На wordpress подключен liqpay 
После checkout страницы перенаправляет на страницу успешного заказа где нужно нажать на кнопку что бы оплатить. 
Нужно пропустить этот шаг а сразу перенаправлять пользователя на страницу оплаты liqpay

Comment: Возможно на этой странице изложены какие-то политики, соглашения либо другая информация юридического характера. Если это так, то не стоит пропускать эту страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать редирект помощью метода POST, в ответ на GET-запрос  - нельзя. Редирект - это ответ сервера с кодом 3хх и указанием в нем URI ресурса, который клиент должен запросить методом GET.

Для вашего случая можно попробывать сформировать POST-запрос из php-скрипта с требуемыми параметрами, а ответ вернуть клиенту.

POST-запрос можно сформировать например с помощью [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php) или [stream_context_create()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-create.php)

Answer (score 0):

Серверу на POST запросы следует возвращать код 307, а не 301. В таком случае клиент (браузер) повторно отправит POST данные на новый адрес.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect#99966